# Html5 Input Pattern doesn't accept right input after correcting

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have a html form with two input fields.
One is for emails and the over is for an amount of money a user can enter.
I have a regex that checks whether the user enters a correct amount bigger than 0.40€.

The problem :
1. I enter an incorrect amount of money ( for example : 0.39€ ) >> Then is says correctly .. "please enter a correct amount ... "
2. then i correct the value to 0.41€ ( that is correct ), but the input field still says "please enter a correct amount ... "

```
<input required="" id="custommoney" name="custommoney" type="text" size="20" maxlength="25" value="25.00€" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Enter a correct amount > 0.40€')" pattern="^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]*(?:(?:.|,)d{2})?)|(?:0(?:(?:.|,)(?:4[1-9]|[5-9]d))))€?$">
```

I couldn't recreate the problem to 100% on jsfiddle but it shows that there is something wrong with the input pattern

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HSJYP/)

I use JQuery and JQuery Mobile !

Comment: That's a serious reqex to check if something is more than 0.40 ?

Comment: yeah i need it because a can't use input type number and firefox doesn't support the min attribute :(